# Websphere: difference between Administrative agent profile and Deployment Profile?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I'm installing a WAS cluster following IBM's Redbook suggestions. 
I need to manage deployments and start/stop of servers from the Web Admin Console. Does the **Deployment** profile will suffice ? or do I need to install also an **Administrative agent profile** on each machine ? ( In other words I'm wondering if the Administrative profile and the Deployment profile are mutually exclusive or, when installed together, they provide some functionalities which I cannot get from the Deployment profile alone).
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to install a cluster, you must use a Deployment Manager profile. Deployment Manager profile provides capabilities for managing a cell. In this cell you will add your nodes, and create clusters using server processes on these nodes. In order to use these features you must be using WebSphere Network Deployment (ND) distribution.

Administrative agent helps you to manage multiple 'base' (standalone) servers. These servers does not have clustering capabilities but are rather suitable for server farms, or for example developer machines. You can run same application on these standalone servers but this will not be a real cluster, in the sense that you won't have centralized installation/uninstallation, load balancing and failover out of the box.